# Deploy Qt ODBC application

Tags: qt, deployment, qt4, odbc, qtsql

My application uses Qt SQL this way

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+QDir::currentPath()+"/database.mdb");
```

and all the rest is done using `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.

Now that deployment stage has come, the application works perfectly on the system where Qt (4.6.3) is installed , but on another *clean* system, there is this error while loading the database

```
"Driver not loaded"
```

I know this has something to do with copying the ODBC plugins... but simply copying `qsqlodbc4.dll` to the app dir and

```
qApp->addLibraryPath(QDir::currentPath());
```

does not work!!

***What is the solution to this**?*

Note: The app is not linked to the driver DLL, it uses Qt plugin mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create this directory structure same as it was on pc having qt installation.

your.app.dir/plugins/your.plugin.folder (i.e your.plugin.folder is sqldrivers)

Copy your plugin under your.app.dir/plugins/your.plugin_folder

Then add this code

```
qApp->addLibraryPath( qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/plugins");
```

I hope this helps.